# Pesquisar uma palavra da Input em um TXT e encontrar palavras que estão na mesma linha em PHP

Tags: php, html, css, txt

Exemplo do arquivo TXT:

> João;1
>
> Pedro;2
>
> Marlon;3
>
> Lucas;4
>
> etc...

Digitando somente o nome no Input preciso que também
apareça o ID do usuário,

**Exemplo do Input:** Marlon

e quando digitar somente nome no Input,
aparecer resultado em Echo ou em

mesmo..
aparecer:

> Nome: Marlon
>
> ID: 3

Se puderem ser bem específicos em relação ao código, pois sou iniciante...

Comment: Esta bem complicado de entender sua pergunta mas parece que esta buscando algo tipo um auto complete ajax

Answer (score 2):

Eu recomendaria que você trabalhe com um arquivo no formato json que é bem mais intuitivo, pelo menos na minha opinião.

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
$json = fopen("caminho do arquivo" . $nomedoseuarquivo . ".json", "w+"); 

//você cria um array na estrutura json
$meujson = array(
'ID'   => '1',
'nome'     => 'William',
);

//encoda o array criado anteriormente e deposita no arquivo  
fwrite($json, json_encode(meu_json));
fclose($json);
```

E para pegar esses dados basta você utilizar a função `json_decode`

```
 //a função file_get_contents pega todo o conteúdo do seu arquivo e deposita na variável file
 $file = file_get_contents("caminho do seu arquivo" . nome do seu arquivo .".json");
 //decodo o conteudo de file e deposito na variável json 
 $json = json_decode($file);
```

A partir dai a variável `$json` vai estar carregando o conteúdo do seu arquivo e basta você buscar os elementos que deseja , uma dica é você utilizar a função `in_array`.

Mas se você quiser optar pela forma tradicional, construí um exemplo de lógica que você pode seguir:

```
<?php

 $nome='oi';//Seria o conteúdo que está vindo do seu post

 //ESTOU LEVANDO EM CONSIDERAÇÃO QUE SEU ARQUIVO VAI ESTAR NA ESTRUTURA  
 //id-NOME E ACONSELHO QUE VOCÊ FAÇA O MESMO)
 $teste = array('2-oi','3-THAU'); //estou simulando oque o file_get_contents 
 //te retornaria

//Esse foreach vai percorrer toda a string que o file_get_contets retorna
foreach($teste as $x)
{

  //pego o id na minha string
  $id = strstr($x,"-",true);

  //echo $id;

  //retiro o id que coletei anteriormente da variável $teste e deposito o resultado na variável $aux
  $aux = str_replace($id,"",$teste);

  //Retiro agora o - que ficou em $aux e deposito em $aux2
  $aux2 = str_replace('-',"",$aux);

  //para vizualizar você não pode usar o echo pois se trata de uma string e não array
//print_r($aux2) ;

//Como se trata de uma string tenho que pegar uma posição, no caso estou verificando se o conteúdo de $nome existe no arquivo, se existir mostro o seu id
  if ($aux2[0] == $nome)
  {
     echo "elemento encontrado :) seu é id :$id";
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'erro';
   }

}
```

De uma pesquisada em cada função que utilizei para assim você também aprender a usar a facilidades do PHP e se quiser testar esse trecho que criei basta jogar ele nesse site http://phptester.net/

Links para você dar uma pesquisada mais a fundo:

in_array: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.in-array.php

json_decode : http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php

json_encode : http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php

Como trabalhar com arquivos em PHP : http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fopen.php

str_replace:https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_string_str_replace

strstr:http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strstr.php

Comment: calma ficou uma bagunça o que falei, vou upar em um lugar o código que possuo...

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/sTur7WJ7

Comment: Da uma olhada na minha resposta principal , desenvolvi um código que vai ajudar a solucionar o seu problema

Comment: http://prntscr.com/l4vo9c
http://prntscr.com/l4vpln
Não entendi é pra juntar meu código com o outro ou só por esse seu código... se for pra acoplar os 2, dá uma ajuda tentei de várias maneiras diferentes e não dá certo..

Comment: é para você adaptar o seu código com oque te passei

Comment: É mas eu não sei... sou tipo super iniciante em php...

Comment: da uma força por favor..

Comment: @KelvynSerrão , esse fórum não tem o objetivo de simplesmente fazer algoritmos quando alguém requisita e sim de ajudar em problemas específicos ou dúvidas tanto que somente eu deu atenção a sua questão.
Se você quer ingressar nessa área por experiencia própria corra atrás , pois nem sempre você vai encontrar a resposta que precisa e além disso o PHP tem uma documentação online super completa ao meu ver 1000X melhor que a de java.

Comment: Caso você curta vídeo aulas recomendo o "CURSO EM VÍDEO" que tem um curso completo de PHP 100% gratuito link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7KzJ7e6EAc&list=PLHz_AreHm4dm4beCCCmW4xwpmLf6EHY9k